# How can I collapse notification in Flutter? using Local Push Notification plugin and CloudFunctions

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using cloud function to send notifications by using device tokens.

```
    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
        notification: {
            title: `updatedBy: ${updatedBy}`,
            body: `nova messagem ${increment}`,
        },

    }
    return fcm.sendToDevice(userToken, payload, options).then((value) => {
        console.log(value.results);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

But, all notification got pilled, I wanna so much to administrate these notification that stay stuck in system tray, is there anyway I can moderate notifications with such "complexity" using these plugins? (Local push Notification, FCM, cloudfunctions) without using native code (kotlin, android)? because I don't know how the android structure work...

I can use cancelAll (of Local push notification)

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll()
```

from Local Push Notification: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/

But is too inflexible

I can also use cancel notification using an specific "ID", but I don't know how to get that notification "id"

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(notificationId)
```

so, How can solve this issue?

In that way I can wisely remove whatever notification I want,
But basically, I just wanna collapse notification that is the same type, like on Whatsapp, when a person send you more than 1 message, and in the system tray, there's only one notification saying that "he" sent more than 1 message (and not a heavy pile of notification).

I just looked at https://github.com/chetdeva/collapsing-notifications/tree/a5e8867e24f53ff8caca761c7faa13242c607dba

This github code is for the article https://medium.com/fueled-engineering/collapsing-fcm-notification-like-a-pro-102a4946b350

would be perfect if it would not too difficult to implement in a flutter project, I also looked at every post here, in stackoverflow, seens that no one yet ever answered this question

[EDIT]: the reason I can't use

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll()
```

It's because I'm using fcm method to listen for notifications, I tried to put that method in some of fcm listener but not succeed.

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on message $message');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');

      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
      },
    );
```

Comment: Have you found a way in which this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "collapse key" mentioned in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl